# A series of possible values

Tags: java, android

I want to make an If statement:

```
if(x == y+n)

{ }

n = [-20...20]
```

where n can be any integer value from -20 to 20.

How to do this in java?

In android I am trying to "synchronize" the ontouch listener to drawView. So I mean an image randomly appears I want to perform a certain action when the image appears....So the "touch" on the screen is pretty precise...

```
----DrawView Class---

setX(rand.nextInt(width-20));
setY(rand.nextInt(height-20));
canvas.drawBitmap(b, getX(), getY(), paint);


public boolean onTouch(View arg0, MotionEvent event) {
if (event.getX() == DrawView.getX()|| event.getY() == DrawView.getY())
{
Certian action...
} 
}
```

so how can I include, DrawView.getX()+[-20...20] and DrawView.getY()+[-20...20]?

Comment: Is the value "set in stone" per whatever the `if` statement says, or is it totally random?

Comment: Could you explain in more detail what you are trying to do?

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com/) I mean *besides* asking random strangers on the internet to do it for you.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with using an `n` value between -20 and 20 inclusive in an if statement; the part that I'm struggling with is what you intend to *assign* to `n` after you're done.

Comment: That does not answer my question.  Do you wish to assign `n` to a specific value between -20 and 20 inclusive?  If so, is it dependent on the result of your if statement?  Please elaborate that.

Comment: @Makoto I was looking for (Math.abs(x - y) <= 20)

Comment: @AndrewThompson Sometimes you get lost in the big picture and it is difficult to realize the small things. Take it easy boy!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you might mean this:

```
int n = x - y;
if (n >= -20 && n <= 20) {
    // etc...
}
```

For your specific range, you can simplify this expression by using `Math.abs`:

```
if (Math.abs(x - y) <= 20) {
    // etc ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Damn it, was easy, got lost in the big picture.

Answer (score 0):

Check whether `x >= y - 20 && x <= y + 20`.